# Word to describe an action

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone know of a proper word/phrase to describe an action whereby you break a file path (e.g. /a/b/c/d) into several pieces such as:

```
/a
/a/b
/a/b/c
/a/b/c/d
```

Comment: What practical *use* is, for example, **/a/b** in your example? And why haven't you included, say, **/b/c** as a possible "sub-component" in the breakdown? Does every "section" have to correspond to a "folder name" in the relevant file system? What about components that refer to remote servers, the Internet, etc.?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I want to list all sub paths of a path.  Now that I've said it, I think the action is called "List all sub paths".  Is there a shorter phrase for that?

Comment: I'm not convinced "list all sub-paths" accurately and unambiguously describes what you're doing. As implied by my first comment, I don't see how that would exclude, for example, **/b/c**. And what about just **a** rather than **/a** ? You seem to be assuming your "initial" path is ***root-relative***, but I'd say that's really something of a special case.

Comment: ...it may be relevant that what you're listing are all (potential) ***"branch" points*** within a hierarchical tree structure, meaning that there could be "sibling" paths at each such point. In a real-world coding context, I might say I was ***parsing*** the tree checking for siblings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, should I name a field IsTreeParsed?

Comment: You have to write your own code. Personally I can't see why I'd want a binary toggle telling me whether I'd "parsed" a full path or not. But I *have* often defined my own C++ class objects in this general area. For example a "parser" object initialised using the original full path, with a "method" function to repeatedly return char*(**next_path**). The way I used to do things, that function would return the 4 lines of your example on consecutive calls, and return a null pointer on the 5th call ("tree fully parsed"; there are no more path elements to return).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Got it. Many thanks.